# Websphere 7 RAD unable to instantiate class

Tags: java, web-services, websphere, wsdl2java

I'm working in Websphere RAD 7.5. I created java code from a SOAP WSDL file (used steps from http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/rsawshlp/v7r5m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.webservice.jaxws.creation.doc%2Ftopics%2Ftsampappjaxws.html). In the course of (those steps) how I created that code, I selected to test the client (moving the slider all the way to the top. I was able to get the code generated and worked past a server publishing error (by deleting the /tmp0 folder and the publish.xml & tmp-data.xml files).

In the course of generating that code (and by my selecting to test the client), I have a new project "...Sample" and "...SamplEAR". That EAR was auto-added to my server. Now when I start the server, I get the error:

"com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.annotation.WASAnnotationHelper collectClasses unable to instantiate class
                                 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: pagecode.sampleBaseCustomerServiceSOAPProxy.TestClient".

The TestClient gets auto-created by the code generation.

I've done a lot of searches for this kind of error and am not coming up with a solution. Can anyone suggest ideas/solutions?